# How to compile SecureUDID with CodeRunner

Tags: ios, objective-c, coderunner

I'm trying to quickly test what kind of results I'd get using SecureUDID before I can use in my Xcode project. In this case I'm using [CodeRunner](http://krillapps.com/coderunner/) but I've never compiled obj-c code outside of Xcode. I've attached the error I'm getting when using the default compilation flag CodeRunner provides for Obj-c files. I've experimented with compilation flag options inspired from the answer for this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918804/how-can-i-include-non-framework-libraries-when-writing-coderunner-documents) but still getting essentially the same error. What compilation flags should I be using? Are there any good resources to learn how to compile obj-c outside of Xcode? Please help thanks!

[image]

Update: It looks like I need to add UIKit and maybe others to the compilation flags now?

[image]

Comment: Wherever or whatever CodeRunner's compile list is called, it doesn't include SecureUDID.m

Comment: How do I add UIKit to CodeRunner? See update

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with Mattia, Xcode is probably the best way to go, however: **CHALLENGE ACCEPTED**.

---

First, let's get CodeRunner to compile with UIKit. In the CodeRunner preferences, duplicate the Objective-C language and name it something like "iOS". I'm using the command that Xcode uses (which you can find in the Log Navigator) as a template. This is also what Mattia was talking about. Set the Compilation Flags to something like this:

> -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -fpascal-strings -O0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -g -fvisibility=hidden -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=5.1 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -F /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

Note the `iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk` path and `-mios-simulator-version-min=5.1` flag. You may need to change these for your own system and versions.

To start, try using the following iOS code (you can also make this your template in the preferences):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow * window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController * viewController;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.viewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.viewController.view.bounds];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:48.0];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    label.text = @"Hello World";
    [self.viewController.view addSubview:label];
    [label release];

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
    }
}
```

If you try to run, it should compile, however the application will crash with this error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit

This is because you're trying to run an iOS app on a Mac, which doesn't have UIKit available; it needs to run in the simulator. Back in the preferences, change Run Command to:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateApplication $PWD/$compiler

Now run the same code. The iOS Simulator should launch and you should see an orange screen with "Hello World":

[image: Hello World]

Now to get it to work with SecureUDID. You'll need to save the code somewhere. Now copy the SecureUDID .h and .m files into the same folder as the saved code. Add `#import "SecureUDID.h"` to the top of the file, change the font size to `14.0`, and change `@"Hello World"` to `[SecureUDID UDIDForDomain:@"com.example.test" usingKey:@"abcdefg"]`. If you run the code, it will complain that it can't find the SecureUDID symbols, as you were seeing. We'll need to add "SecureUDID.m" to the Compilation Flags. So you can reuse the iOS language in CodeRunner, you can add this to the flags in Custom Run, however you'll need to deal with that modal view each time you want to run.

And there you go:

[image: SecureUDID]

Unfortunately, logging will not appear in the CodeRunner console, but you can open up the Mac app, Console, to see them. I'm also getting some extra black padding. Not yet sure what I'm doing wrong to get that.

Answer (score 3):

That error means the linker can't find the implementation for SecureUDID (either the .m file or the library). If you go to coderunner's preferences you can set the command line options and point it to the implementation but honestly it'll likely be faster to make a new project in Xcode to test this. Coderunner is awesome but when you have to deal with external libraries/source files it's easier to just make a throwaway Xcode project.

UPDATE:

UIKit is an iOS framework so it's not with your regular frameworks like Foundation. Assuming you have Xcode 4.3 installed you can find UIKit at:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

You need to add that directory to your frameworks search path and then add:

-framework UIKit

to you compilation parameters in Coderunner.

The real answer to your question though is to stop trying to use Coderunner and use Xcode. Coderunner is meant for writing small code snippets without having to do all the configuration to create an Xcode project. In this case what you need IS all the configuration and Xcode allows you to do, so rather than fighting with coderunner to make it behave like a full IDE you should just use Xcode - you'll be much happier for it.